# Is it possible to change angular bootstrap uib-dropdown templateUrl dynamically?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, faceted-search, angular-bootstrap

I want to change the `uib-dropdown` template dynamically when the user clicks one of its `<li>`, just like he could "navigate" within that dropdown.

I tried to make it via `templateUrl`, but nor the `ng-templates` nor standalone partials can successfully change the dropdown template dynamically, just like this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LRtlALkTuRFwZMQPWOHe) demonstrates.

My goal is to create a faceted navigation via this dropdown to build query visually, as seen on [Fieldbook's Sprint tracker (account required)](https://fieldbook.com), which is something really like [Pure Angular Advanced Searchbox](https://github.com/tybeck/pure-angular-advanced-searchbox), but I'm having overwhelming issues using this library.

Is this possible to achieve using just AngularJS and angular-bootstrap?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for [**something like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/rcjWu/), but in only one dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Demo(try the last one):

http://plnkr.co/edit/1yLmarsQFDzcLd0e8Afu?p=preview

#### How to get it to work?

Based on your plunkr, you should change

```
<div class="input-group" uib-dropdown auto-close="disabled">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Click to start a visual query search..." autocomplete="off" uib-dropdown-toggle/>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" ng-if="ctrl.dropdownReady" uib-dropdown-menu template-url="{{ctrl.dropdownTemplateFour}}">
    </ul>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="input-group" uib-dropdown auto-close="disabled"  ng-if="ctrl.dropdownReady">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Click to start a visual query search..." autocomplete="off" uib-dropdown-toggle/>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" uib-dropdown-menu template-url="{{ctrl.dropdownTemplateFour}}">
    </ul>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

In which the `ng-if="ctrl.dropdownReady"` is moved to the `div.input-group`.

And change

```
vm.dropdownReady = false;
console.log('vm.dropdownReady =', vm.dropdownReady, ' partial = ', partial);
switch (template) {
  case 'word':
    partial ? vm.dropdownTemplateFour = 'word-dropdown-dom.template.html' : vm.dropdownTemplateThree = 'word-dropdown-dom.html';
    break;
  case 'main':
    partial ? vm.dropdownTemplateFour = 'main-dropdown-dom.template.html' : vm.dropdownTemplateThree = 'main-dropdown-dom.html';
    break;
}
vm.dropdownReady = true;
```

to

```
vm.dropdownReady = false;
console.log('vm.dropdownReady =', vm.dropdownReady, ' partial = ', partial);
switch (template) {
  case 'word':
    partial ? vm.dropdownTemplateFour = 'word-dropdown-dom.template.html' : vm.dropdownTemplateThree = 'word-dropdown-dom.html';
    break;
  case 'main':
    partial ? vm.dropdownTemplateFour = 'main-dropdown-dom.template.html' : vm.dropdownTemplateThree = 'main-dropdown-dom.html';
    break;
}
$timeout(function(){
  vm.dropdownReady = true;
});
```

Which has a `$timeout` wrap the `vm.dropdownReady = true;`. And you should inject the `$timeout` by hand;

#### Keep the menu open

According to the [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#dropdown), we can choose the initial state of drop menu with `is-open` attr. And we can listen the toggle event with `on-toggle` attr. So if we want to keep the menu open after user clicking the input, we should set the attributes of `uib-dropdown` like this:

```
<div class="input-group" uib-dropdown auto-close="disabled"  ng-if="ctrl.dropdownReady" is-open="ctrl.open" on-toggle="ctrl.toggled(open)">
```

And in controller:

```
vm.toggled = function (open) {
    // the parameter `open` is maintained by *angular-ui/bootstrap*
    vm.open=open;//we don't need to init the `open` attr, since it's undefined at beginning
}
```

With these things done, once the menu is open, it doesn't close without user clicking the input again.

#### Why?

Let's check this [snippet](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/761db7b4b7da993fe4f89a83163aa1243113ab24/src/dropdown/dropdown.js#L338):

```
$templateRequest(self.dropdownMenuTemplateUrl)
    .then(function(tplContent) {
    templateScope = scope.$new();
    $compile(tplContent.trim())(templateScope, function(dropdownElement) {
        var newEl = dropdownElement;
        self.dropdownMenu.replaceWith(newEl);//important
        self.dropdownMenu = newEl;
        $document.on('keydown', uibDropdownService.keybindFilter);
    });
});
```

The snippet above shows how does **angular-ui/bootstrap** use the **template-url** attr to retrive template and take it into effect. It replaces the original `ul` element with a newly created element. That's why the `uib-dropdown-menu` and `template-url` is missing after clicking the `ul`. Since they don't exist, you can't change the template-url with angular binding anymore.

The reason executing `vm.dropdownReady = true;` immediately after the `vm.dropdownReady = false;` doesn't work is that angular have no chance to dectect this change and execute the "ng-if" to actually remove the dom. You must make the toggling of `vm.dropdownReady` asynchronous to give angular a chance to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your thorough analysis of the problem, however, the 4th input you refer to in this answer doesn't work like expected: the dropdown template changes, but it's necessary to click its input field again to show the new template.
What I expect is that the user could actually navigate within that dropdown, passing from template to template, visiting various `<ul>` to compose the query he likes.

Comment: @Gargaroz  What do you think about it now? :D

Comment: Awesome, you did it; so if I got it right, `autoclose="disabled"` doesn't prevent the dropdown to "close" once we dynamically change its template, hence the need of manually handle `is-open` with the `on-toggle` function, am I right?

Comment: What I think? Dude I think you have too few upvotes than the "wrong" answer, sadly. But I can help with 150 shmackeroni just for you dude. There you go, you are a beast.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D. The reason why the menu is closed after changing its template is that we destroy the whole dropdown menu with ng-if="ctrl.dropdownReady". It can't have any open state left.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: You should assign the value of `template-url` using a controller var which changes as the user select any of the options, then you "repaint" the component, this way the "new" dropdown is "repainted" with the new template.

Yes, it's possible according to [the official documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), though I've never done this before.

You can specify a *uib-dropdown-menu settings* called `template-url`.

According to the docs the

> default value is none

and

> you may specify a template for the dropdown menu

Comment: Which is what [I just did (watch it by clicking this link)](http://plnkr.co/edit/LRtlALkTuRFwZMQPWOHe) but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code is according to what I just said :)OK.Now, I think it only needs a tweak to get it working properly.The problem is that it seems that the component once rendered doesn't notice the template change (it doesn't "watch" it),so you could try(and this is what I meant by saying "repaint") delete the html node and re-insert it (now with the new template).How?Use a `ng-if` condition when click `setDropdownTemplate` set a var to `false`(this will remove the component from dom),then, once done this set that var again to `true` (and this will "repaint" the component again).Pls, Give me feedback

Comment: The condition would go something like this: `<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" uib-dropdown-menu template-url="{{ctrl.dropdownTemplateTwo}}" data-ng-if="ctrl.readyToShow">` and `readyToShow` would be set to `false' and then to `true` again as I described

Comment: Done, [check it out](http://plnkr.co/edit/LRtlALkTuRFwZMQPWOHe?p=preview), but unfortunately for me it doesn't work yet.

Comment: It seems it's just the behavior of the component. That's a pity :( Anyways I'll do some more research. I'll give you some feedback if I find something else useful

Comment: @Gargaroz, in the solution described above by me... did your try it enclosing the `readyToShow=true` part inside a `$timeout`? If not, could you try it?

Comment: you mean just like [blackmiaool has done in the 4th input (line 37-39) of my plunker fork?](http://plnkr.co/edit/1yLmarsQFDzcLd0e8Afu?p=preview) Because that doesn't work either.